# Migration from SP 2010 to SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a requirement that we need to migrate the existing SharePoint 2010 OnPrem Farm solution into SPO. Please find the list of customizations and restrictions w.r.t environment.

1. Current O365 has single tenant model. For this model, we have 3 different site collections for Dev, QA and Prod. Can we have different app catalog site in single tenant model ? In this model, if we have only single APP Catalog, and developer upload the app in catalog, and QA found some bugs, even it is ready for install in Prod as well. How we can maintain the build/release management under this single tenant model. Please clarify.
2. Customer dont have provision of Azure / On Prem server to save the cost. For all customizations, we need to do through SharePoint Hosted app. Without having the option to host for provider hosted app(remote provisiong) how to implement the below artifacts using Sharepoint hosted app.

   1. Custom Site Templates
   2. Feature Stapling
   3. Branding - Master pages, css, images, scripts
   4. Provisioning List/ Document Libraries

Please clarify and guide me about how to proceed with solution design and architecture for the above requirements.

Comment: this question contains multiple questions, it is better to split it into multiple question...easy to get the answer.s

Comment: Ok. Let me split this question into multiple

Answer (score 1):

You cant have more than 1 app catalog in one tenant, in your situation what i think.

- You should go to multi tenant environment, one for Dev, one for QA and one for Production. once your testing complete then you can deploy your app in Prod Tenant.
- Other is solution dont install the app in prod but it has some risk. If users have permission and they see it and install without informing anybody.